# How to natively enable TRIM in Sierra for a 3rd-party SSD?

Tags: ssd, trim

**My question is:** How to natively enable TRIM in Sierra for a 3rd-party SSD?

A solution I found involves installing an "out of the App Store" app that will probably ask for admin credentials etc which I generally don't like.

Is there a native way in OS Sierra to enable TRIM ? Since many paid apps like the one I mentioned are just GUIs for basic BSD tools already in Sierra.

I'm all new to SSDs and just heard about TRIM and how it can help boost the life of your SSD etc.

Thanks !

Comment: `sudo trimforce enable` worked on El Capitan, not sure if it's possible with Sierra

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open a terminal window, then type `sudo trimforce enable`. Enter your password into the command line, trim will be turned on. Devices seen below will not work with TRIM commands. If you are unfamiliar with using the command line, I'd see the bottom of this post for guided images.

[image]

To enable trim, see below

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I'm a bit worried about the "as-is" nature of the disclaimer. Is TRIM risky or reliable ? Or is it full experimentation ? Would it be better to use something like Trim Enabler ? : https://cindori.org/trimenabler/

Comment: Only fails on drives that are older... new drives should be fine.

Comment: But do you need TRIM anyway ? My SSD is recent I think, it's a Crucial MX300.

Comment: In short, no. Your choice of Trim and/or GC won't harm the drive.  It'll affect its performance.  Both features exist to speed up write performance which would otherwise decline over time.  Using both is optimal and recommended for heavier write use but one or the other ought to cope with typical end usage.

Comment: The code you quote regarding trim support is from the linux kernel.  https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/drivers/ata/libata-core.c#n4563   and isn't about ALL trim but specifically queued trim.  Also it sounds like a lot of the Samsung issues were not actually samsung issues, but a kernel bug.  https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?311182-SSD-and-discard-mount-option&p=1769289#post1769289   So not sure this list of "SSDs that don't work with TRIM" is really relevant for MacOS.

Comment: AFAIK HFS+ doesn't issue queued TRIM commands, so as long as the drive isn't converted to APFS, that didn't really arrive until macOS 10.13 "High Sierra".